# Autoexec.bat equivalents for Ubuntu that run with root privelidges?

Tags: 12.04, boot, security

On Ubuntu there must be several "`autoexec.bat`" equivalents as I can see files like `rc.local` which seem to do very little because the comments in the file says it doesn't work by default and I tried putting this command in there and it didn't work.

What I need to know is where I place this line.

```
echo 0 | /usr/bin/tee -a /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

I also saw a `rc.local` in `/etc/init.d` as well but where I would place the cmd to make it work is a mystery as there are two functions in there so do I place it at the end of one of those functions or at the last line?

The command needs root permission to run and ideally it should be executed when the computer starts. As the command dims the keyboard of my MacBook Air.

Also, I would also like to know what file I'd need to edit if only a specific user would have this command run. As its an root command and I don't want to give admin or sudo access to that user I would like this command to execute as root when the user logs in and the user cannot stop that command from running.

---

Additional Discoveries

---

`$HOME/.profile` is the login script but doesn't run as root, it works if you sudo the command but thats not want I need.

The `/etc/profile`is weird, it doesn't execute at boot but when I go into a shell and execute `sudo -i`" it runs as soon as the sudo goes into interactive mode

---

A neat short cut

---

With version 14.04, might have worked in earlier versions, you simply add a line to crontab using `sudo crontab -e` and add a line "@reboot whatevercommandwithfullpath" and it works. But with this new version I created a upstart script which is closer to how it should be done.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is not supposed to execute at boot. It runs for all Bourne-style login shells, when the shells start. So, it runs together with `.profile` files in users' home directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a daemon witch is the right way to do it. However it's a little harder than rc.local.

see here : https://superuser.com/questions/530071/installing-daemon-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-system

detailed help (you can take example of /etc/init.d/hostname) :

copy the skeleton :

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/keyboard_backlight
```

edit the skeleton :

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/keyboard_backlight
```

search for this

```
do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
                || return 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS \
                || return 2
        # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
        # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
        # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.

}
```

and change it like this :

```
do_start()
{
        echo 0 | /usr/bin/tee -a /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
}
```

Comment out or delete the lines inside the do_stop and the do_reload

```
do_stop()
{
}
do_reload()
{
}
```

Save the file.

Give the execution permission to the file :

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/keyboard_backlight
```

Test your service :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/keyboard_backlight start
```

If everything ok, load your service for startup

```
sudo update-rc.d keyboard_backlight defaults 99
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, for login shells they run in this order:

```
1./etc/profile
2./etc/profile.d/ files
3.$HOME/.bash_profile
4.$HOME/.bash_login
```

However, I'm unsure if the /etc/profile gets executed before any users actually login but it is worth trying just in case I am right.

Answer (score 1):

Is this still working?

> This script will run before the graphical interface appears...
>
> 1. Make the script with desired commands. vi file.sh
> 2. Copy the script to /etc/init.d cp file.sh /etc/init.d/file.sh
> 3. Change permission to allow execution chmod +x /etc/init.d/file.sh
> 4. At /etc/init.d Link it! sudo update-rc.d file.sh start 99 2 . (do not forget the "." at the end of the command)
>
> If you need to disable this script in a near future: sudo update-rc.d
>   -f file.sh remove

It seems quite easy this way and you can keep different scripts for different things

Answer (score 0):

most probably you are looking for `/etc/rc.local`

if you add any command before `exit 0` that should run as root.

Don't forget to change permisson to executable for both `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/init.d/rc.local` unless it won't work, leave as is if they are already executable.

Comment: Did that already, I mentioned that in my original question. Command executes as I redirected output to my home directory so I know it executed. But the command itself didn't dim the keyboard :(

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that you have a working script (with the right file permissions),  with the name `myscript.sh`;

`cd` to to the folder that you have the script in and do:

```
sudo cp myscript.sh     /etc/profile.d/
```

This will copy the script to a place that contains scripts that are executed on boot so that the next time you boot it should work.