# Upstart job not recognized

Tags: 14.04, upstart, services

I wrote a simple upstart job:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

exec dnscrypt-proxy -E -R cisco-ipv6
```

It starts properly on boot, but is still not recognized by `service --status-all` and `initctl list`. I have searched the web and found some similar issues caused by syntax error, so I checked with `init-checkconf`, and got a "syntax ok". Am I missing something?

**Edit**:

I found this related question: [Correct way to install a custom upstart service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299371/correct-way-to-install-a-custom-upstart-service)

It turns out that I was missing `sudo` when running `initctl list`. Still it does not expain why some service require root permission to be displayed, while others does not, as all `.conf` files have exactly the same owner and permission.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your `dnscrypt-proxy -E -R cisco-ipv6` need networking and your init script running before network and other needed service so write you script like

```
start on started networking
```

or

```
start on network-interface-up INTERFACE=eth0
```

if your service need file system then you can write

```
start on filesystem and started networking
```

and 
if this depend on other service also then include

```
start on started other-service
```

you can learn from [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on)